# Teaching game development with Ruby

Tags: 3d, jmonkeyengine, ruby, teaching

I want to teach game development to kids as part of a course (year-long) involving Ruby.  Unfortunately it looks like the game development kits available in Ruby (even in the form of bindings) are pretty limited.

Is the best solution to go with JRuby and use jMonkeyEngine through the JVM?  I'd love to have the kids play with creating very basic 3d games.  Is there another better solution for Ruby or on the JVM through JRuby?

Average age of kids is probably 9 to 12, with some as young as 5 and as old as 18.

Comment: Why, in the name of all that is right and good, would you want to use Ruby to teach games? And that is an honest question, not just a jab (although it is partly a jab). I'd use something like Alice by Carnegie-Mellon University, that teaches Java in a visual environment. It provides an easy visually driven framework in which learners can grasp the elements of Java bit-by-bit.

Comment: I'm teaching Ruby as a way to teach programming in general, not just for games.  Having 3d graphics and game development in the curriculum is a bonus.  I believe Ruby is better for this purpose than Alice or other visual programming environments for kids like Scratch.

Comment: Even with Alice out of the picture (and it is a fantastic tool) I still wouldn't really recommend Ruby for games. What aspect in it do you favour, which you believe would benefit the learners over the choice of a more popular beginning language such as straight Java, ActionScript?

Comment: @Nick - I believe Ruby is better based on my experience with my 6 year old son and more limited experience with other kids using Scratch vs Ruby code.  These visual development tools for kids seem like an unnecessary intermediate step to coding that doesn't speed up learning.  The only major impediment to kids, even very young, coding is typing.  And that's solved with a couple weeks of daily practice (which can be fun in itself).

Comment: @NickWiggill - I'm not trying to teach games, I'm teaching programming in general.  Games is just 1 part.  So Java and ActionScript may have more game development support.  But Ruby has far easier and more elegant syntax and code mechanisms (closures, duck typing, modifiable classes, etc) and better web development tools and libraries.  I can use Java too with JRuby if need be (though would prefer more Ruby-esque solutions).

Comment: Fair enough. Have you tried Flash or JS+HTML5 Canvas? Results-driven learning carries a huge advantage. Flash is possibly the most common rapid application development tool for game developers... when you just want to get something on the screen, faster than fast. And the syntax is not tough, as these things go. I can test a simple AI, rendering method, or geometric algorithm in a few minutes in Flash. I would concern myself far more with what kids can see as a result of 5 minutes work, than closures, duck typing etc. That's coming from an ex-teacher of people of all ages, not just a gamedev.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not here to proselytise, I am for whatever tool does the job best. If I can't answer your question about Ruby, and that's your choice, I won't annoy you further. ;)

Comment: @NickWiggill - You are not at all annoying me, I very much appreciate your thoughts.  I did consider JS + HTML5 (webgl and other technologies make 3d graphics not only easy but easily shareable which is a huge plus for kids).  The problem was getting started.  A younger kid feels overwhelmed with all the technologies required to understand to even get started.  Ruby is just so much easier.  Flash is great for games and simple graphics, but not much else.  Kids seem to be pretty excited by even simple text input/output in the beginning.  If I can add game dev easily, I think this is best..

Comment: Re JS, Canvas, WebGL -- yes, the problem there is maturity. The other problem is that sometimes it's a little too flexible and you get into errors very easily that way. Re ActionScript & games, no, not really. Remember that Flex _is_ Flash, and is used heavily in eg. the finance sector, for one. Nearly every language out there was developed to serve a particular purpose; doesn't mean that as they mature they don't come to serve other purposes just as well. But, Flash IDE doesn't come free (it contains the art tools that the kids could use). FlashDevelop is great and free, but no art tools.

Comment: Flash/Flex is great, if I was only teaching games or other interactive graphical web-based apps, I might choose that for the kids.  But given that I also want to teach web development, databases, 3d graphics, networking, multithreading, etc, that means I'll also have to teach another programming language.  I'd rather teach 1 language and then teach the other technologies/algorithms.

Comment: In that case, my final suggestion is to pick something general purpose, something that is a cornerstone of the software development industry, something less obscure than Ruby, such as Java, with or without Alice.

Comment: @NickWiggill - Java was a VERY strong candidate in my mind.  Ruby has 2 significant advantages over it and you can always use JRuby to get at some of Java's advantages (like more extensive 3rd party libraries including 3d and game engines).  Ruby has more elegant syntax and mechanisms that are far easier for kids to get started with and grow with.  And Ruby has Ruby on Rails, for which there is no equal in the Java world.

Comment: JS, Java, and Flash are varying levels of good for teaching programming and doing game development. However, my actual, honest suggestion would be Unity. It's free, it does 3d, and it doesn't need much/anything to get *something* on the screen. Additionally, please move extended comment discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) in the future.

Comment: How old are these kids?  I mean, what grade level are we talking about?

Comment: @TrevorPowell - Updated question to reflect age range.

Comment: Based on the age ranges (which pretty much covers every age of kids in school...), you are going to have a very hard time teaching the kids web programming and databases, let alone "3d graphics, networking, multithreading" and anything else you might think of, unless you are somehow teaching a class of super-geniuses. How much 3d graphics programming have you, personally, done?

Comment: @thedaian - the idea is you start out learning how to type.  Then you learn the basics of programming.  And you keep progressing as fast as you are capable of.  So by the 3rd year of learning on a daily basis (possibly far sooner for advanced or older kids) you'll get to web programming.  Then databases, then graphics, then 3d graphics, then game development.  Personally, I've written some basic games in c++ with OpenGL a long time ago (if memory servers OpenGL was at v1.2).

Comment: How could a kid that doesn't even understand a Java(or C++ as java is based on it) syntax, understand multithreading, matrix math, 3D,  networking, etc? I think that, if you use Java, it would be much much better than using ruby and "fixing" its problems with JRuby. If you want them to understand Java's things, teach Java to them. Or else, teach Ruby now, when they got ready, teach java and anything else you want to.

Comment: As it stands, this question really isn't fit for this site. There's a massive difference between what to use to teach a 5 year old programming and what to use to teach an 18 year old programming, and one year isn't at all enough time to even begin 3d programming starting from basic Ruby. Additionally, "which technology should I use" questions are off topic per the FAQ. You're welcome to join the chat and ask the question there, where can get a better idea of what you're actually doing.

Comment: @thedaian my question wasn't really about the technology, I had already decided on Ruby.  My question is if JRuby with jMonkeyEngine is the best way to go for teaching kids very basic 3d game dev, or if there is a better alternative.

Comment: @at. Choos a "best" is offtopic too. Choosing between JRuby or jMonkeyEngine is choosing a technology too.

Comment: If this question wasn't closed, my answer would have been use Ruby2D. It's a really simple (less dependencies) graphics engine that would be ideal for teaching basic programming skills. http://www.ruby2d.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, JRuby is probably going to be your most flexible option. An alternative is [ruby-processing](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing/wiki), but of course that's geared more toward constructing visualizations than efficient game systems.

Is 3D a requirement? A lot more options open up to you without it such as Rubygame, Chingu, Gosu, etc.

---

Now to play devil's advocate, why Ruby over another "beginner-friendly" language?

Python has pyglet. And Panda3D.

And how about Scala? It seems much more friendly to start with compared to Java. Hello World is just this:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Retains the structure and static typing of Java, but offers less verbose syntax and to option for more dynamic typing and, if you care to get into it, functional programming like you'd get with Ruby blocks. You obviously wouldn't want to throw lambdas around in your game loop, but shader programming has functional characteristics so the learning is still valuable and relevant.

And you can import Java libraries and thus use JMonkey, Slick2D, or whatever you need. It also has a REPL, which I think would be a hugely beneficial educational tool and reason to go with something like Python, Ruby, or Scala.

Comment: 3D is not a requirement, but a big plus.  Unity3D also works with Python, so Python was definitely under consideration.  But Python doesn't have an equivalent Rails framework (no Django isn't).  And I personally like Ruby better.  Finally, Ruby has JRuby to take advantage of Java libraries (maybe Python has something similar?  But not as popular).

Comment: Jython has been around for longer than JRuby, and matches up with CPython 2.5.2. And Django's a pretty good replacement for Rails if you're willing to relinquish clever block DSLs and lean only slightly more in the direction of configuration vs convention. There's also plenty of others to choose from: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks I like using Tornado ( http://tornadoweb.org ) as a Sinatra-like framework. The thing to remember about Unity, is that it's not actually Python--it's Boo, which was built before the DLR and so you find yourself coding more statically than proper Python.

Comment: @at. I also find Python to be more widely usable outside of web technology than Ruby. The number of Python bindings for C and C++ libraries is staggering. There's also NumPy/SciPy to consider if you ever want to take a dive into scientific computing. I like Ruby a lot. I love blocks and want to try to get a protoyping workflow going with Ruby. But it's hard to deny the diversity of Python libraries available. There's some benefit to that.